# Delphi XE5, Android - Store resources in XML

Tags: xml, delphi, android-resources, delphi-xe5

In **Java** projects the `res/` directory contains all the resources (layouts, animation, ...), and I can access them using resource IDs that are generated in my project's `R` class. I find it very convenient, and I get used to it.
In **Delphi XE5** projects I create a window at runtime: create any `JView`, create `JNativeLayout`, add `JView` to the layout via `SetControl(JView)`, set size and position manually. Or retrieve a root view and add created `JView` as a child. Surely, it's not the best way... but I can't think of any better ideas.
To access a resource I write smth like this:

```
String version := JStringToString(SharedActivity.getResources.getString( SharedActivity.getResources.getIdentifier(StringToJString('R.string.version'), StringToJString('string'), SharedActivity.getPackageName) ));
```

So questions are:
 - How can I store resources in XML?
 - Is there an easier way to access a resource by its identifier?

Comment: I'm sure if you wanted to define a class called `R` and give it a method that encapsulates most of that long expression, you could. And what's stopping you from storing whatever you want in whatever file format you want? You can use XML or anything else. Not sure what that has to do with putting controls on forms, though.

Comment: If you code in Delphi, well code in Delphi. Add resources and use TResourceStream to read them.

Comment: Delphi doesn't use the Android SDK resources system - instead, it uses its own so that you can single-source between different platforms. What exactly are you wanting to use SDK-style resources for...?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, ok, I will pay attention to TResourceStream.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston, I want to load layout/animation from XML. (I don't know how to make animation at runtime)

Comment: To be honest, if you want to use Android SDK controls using Android SDK XML layouts, Delphi won't be the tool for you - I take it you have taken a conscious decision to avoid FMX? There's an open source project for covering the controls themselves, but the layouts are another matter so far as I am aware.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston, now it's clear, thank you! 
Yes, I am. I avoid FMX because I want to implement my own components.

Comment: Hmm, in the context of a Delphi project, it would be easier to write custom components as custom FMX controls...